# How to remove line spacing between line in Textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, css

I am new in PHP. I have a code in which i use multiple Text Editor with Jquery. Through Text editor i store values in mysql db. After That i have a page on which i fetch some fields from db and apply crud operations Like View Update and Delete. **Now here is my problem.** When i click on Update button it increase line spacing between the lines. Every time when i update my data it increase line space. In div tag i use CSS Line Height tag but its not working for me.

**Here is my code.**

Code for create a document

**test.php**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>Notification Letter.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownbutton.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcolorpicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#editor1').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor2').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor3').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor4').jqxEditor({ 
            });

             $('#editor5').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor6').jqxEditor({ 
            });
            $('#editor7').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor8').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor9').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor10').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor11').jqxEditor({
            });

        });
    </script>

    <div style="margin-top: 30px; width: 800px;">

    <div style=" margin:auto; width:60px; height:auto; align: middle">
    <img src="image/pacra_logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div style="margin:auto; width:auto; text-align:center; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-variant: small-caps; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold">
    The Pakistan Credit Rating Agency Limited 
    <hr>
    </div>
    </div>
    <form action="test1.php" method="POST">
    <div style="margin-top: 30px; width: 800px;">

                <div style="width: auto; float:" contenteditable="true">
                <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1">
                 NL FY 15-147 (-040515) 
                </textarea>
                </div>

           <div style=" margin-top:30px; width:35%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px" contenteditable="true">
           <textarea name="editor2" id="editor2">
                <b>Mr. Shahid Islam </b></br> 
                Managing Director</br>
               Oil Company Limited</br>
                Karachi
                </textarea>
           </div>

            <div style=" margin-top:30px; margin-left:220px; width:35%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:right; font-size:14px" contenteditable="true" >
            <textarea name="editor3" id="editor3">
            <strong><u>Confidential</u></strong>
            <p>May 04, 2015</p>
            <br>
            </textarea>
            </div>


          <div style="margin-top:250px; margin-right:auto; width:auto; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:center; 
          font-variant:small-caps; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold" contenteditable="true" >
          <textarea name="editor4" id="editor4">
  Oil Company Limited
       </br>Entity Ratings Update
          </textarea>
          </div>


         <div style=" margin-top:25px; width:20%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:16px" contenteditable="true" > 
         <textarea name="editor5" id="editor5">
         Dear Mr. Islam
         </textarea>
         </div> 




    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 800px; text-align:justify; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:14px" contenteditable="true" >
    <textarea name="editor6" id="editor6">

            This has reference to our communication and discussion with you and your team regarding rating of  Oil Company Limited (). We appreciate that management has been forthcoming in providing all the requisite information. This has enabled PACRA in forming the right ration opinion.</br>
            PACRA has decided to hold  rating with AA category. This category captures credit worthiness of very strong enterprises. Within the category though, the rating has been revised to AA [Previous Rating AA+]. This primarily captures the uncertainty emanating from circular debt, of which has become an inseparable part. This is likely to persist until structural reforms are implemented.</br>
             At the same time, the rating incorporate  leading position in the OMC sector, its state-of-the-art infrastructure and its ability to manage its financial profile through a tough cash cycle.</br> 
            We are enclosing a press release being that issued in this regard.</br>

            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:30px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px" contenteditable="true" >
    <textarea name="editor7" id="editor7">
     Yours truly 
    </textarea>
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:110px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px; font-variant:small-caps" contenteditable="true" >
    <textarea name="editor8" id="editor8">
    <strong>ssssssssssssssssssssssss</strong>
    </textarea>
    </div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin:auto; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px;" contenteditable="true" >
    <textarea name="editor9" id="editor9">
  Cheif Operating Officer
  </textarea>
    </div>    

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:50px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px;" contenteditable="true" >
    <textarea name="editor10" id="editor10">
  Encl: 1) Press Release
    </textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:300px">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    </div>

    </form>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:250px; width:800px; float:left; text-align:center; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:18px;">
    <hr>
 <strong>Awami Complex FB-1, Usman Block, New Garden Town, Lahore-54600, Pakistan</strong>  
 </br>PABX: 92(42)35869507 Fax: 92(42)35830425 Email: pacra@pacra.com 
 </br>www.pacra.com
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Code for Data Update**

**edit.php**

```
<?php
    require 'database.php';
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }

    if ( null==$id ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    //------------------------------------------Update-------------------------------- 
    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
$editor1 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor1']);
$editor2 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor2']);
$editor3 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor3']);
$editor4 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor4']);
$editor5 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor5']);
$editor6 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor6']);
$editor7 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor7']);
$editor8 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor8']);
$editor9 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor9']);
$editor10 =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor10']);
if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit"){
$status=$_POST['submit'];}

if($_POST['submit'] == "Save"){
$status=$_POST['submit'];}


if($_POST['submit'] == "Approve"){
$status=$_POST['submit'];}

if($_POST['submit'] == "Re-Submit"){
$status=$_POST['submit'];}

$valid = true;
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $sql = "UPDATE test1  set editor1 ='$editor1', editor2 ='$editor2', editor3 ='$editor3',
                                        editor4 ='$editor4', editor5 = '$editor5', editor6 ='$editor6',
                                        editor7 ='$editor7', editor8 ='$editor8', editor9 ='$editor9',
                                        editor10 ='$editor10', status='$status'  WHERE id ='$id'";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($editor1,$editor12,$editor3,$editor4,$editor5,$editor6,$editor7,$editor8,$editor9,
            $editor10,$status,$id));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }





/*$query = mysql_query("UPDATE test  set editor1 ='$editor1', editor2 ='$editor2', editor3 ='$editor3',
                                        editor4 ='$editor4', editor5 = '$editor5', editor6 ='$editor6',
                                        editor7 ='$editor7', editor8 ='$editor8', editor9 ='$editor9',
                                        editor10 ='$editor10', status='$status'  WHERE id ='$id'");
            header("Location: index.php");*/
    }
    else { 
          }


    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pacra1");

         $id2 = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test1 where id='$id2'";

            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $row= (mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC));

$editor1 =($row['editor1']);
$editor2 =($row['editor2']);
$editor3 =($row['editor3']);
$editor4 =($row['editor4']);
$editor5 =($row['editor5']);
$editor6 =($row['editor6']);
$editor7 =($row['editor7']);
$editor8 =($row['editor8']);
$editor9 =($row['editor9']);
$editor10 =($row['editor10']);
$status =($row['status']);




    ?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newstyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownbutton.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcolorpicker.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxeditor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#editor1').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor2').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor3').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });

            $('#editor4').jqxEditor({ 
            });

             $('#editor5').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor6').jqxEditor({ 
            });
            $('#editor7').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor8').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor9').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor10').jqxEditor({tools: 'bold italic underline | left center right'
            });
            $('#editor11').jqxEditor({
            });

        });
    </script>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 800px">

    <div style=" margin:auto; width:60px; height:auto; align: middle">
    <img src="image/pacra_logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div style="margin:auto; width:auto; text-align:center; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-variant: small-caps; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold">
    The Credit Rating Agency Limited 
    <hr></div>
    <form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="POST" > 
                <div style="width: 30%; float:left; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true">

                <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1">
                <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor1))?(nl2br($editor1)):'';?> 
                </textarea>
                </div>
                 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
           <div style=" margin-top:30px; width:35%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:14px; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true">
           <textarea name="editor2" id="editor2">
                <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor2))?(nl2br($editor2)):'';?>
           </textarea>
           </div>
            <div style=" margin-top:30px; margin-left:220px; width:35%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:right; font-size:14px; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true">
            <textarea name="editor3" id="editor3">
            <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor3))?(nl2br($editor3)):'';?>
            </textarea>
            </div>
             <div style="clear: both;"></div>
          <div style="margin-top:40px; margin-right:auto; width:auto; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:center; font-variant:small-caps; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true">
          <textarea name="editor4" id="editor4">
         <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor4))?(nl2br($editor4)):'';?> 
         </textarea>
          </div>
         <div style=" margin-top:20px; width:20%; float:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:left; font-size:16px; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true">
         <textarea name="editor5" id="editor5"> 
         <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor5))?(nl2br($editor5)):'';?>
         </textarea>
         </div> 

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 800px; text-align:justify; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:14px; line-height:0.5" contenteditable="true">
            <textarea name="editor6" id="editor6">
            <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor6))?(nl2br($editor6)):'';?>
   </textarea>
        </div>

    <div style="margin-top:30px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px" contenteditable="true">
    <textarea name="editor7" id="editor7">
    <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor7))?(nl2br($editor7)):'';?>
    </textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top:100px; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px; font-variant:small-caps" contenteditable="true">
    <textarea name="editor8" id="editor8">
    <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor8))?(nl2br($editor8)):'';?>
    </textarea>
    </div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin:auto; width:auto; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px;" contenteditable="true">
    <textarea name="editor9" id="editor9">
  <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor9))?(nl2br($editor9)):'';?>
    </textarea>
    </div>    
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top:40px; width:auto; height:30px float:left; text-align:left; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:16px;" contenteditable="true">
    <textarea name="editor10" id="editor10">

  <?php echo !empty(nl2br($editor10))?(nl2br($editor10)):'';?>
  </textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:100px">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Approve">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Re-Submit">
    </div>
    </form>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top:70px; width:800px; float:left; text-align:center; font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:18px;">
    <hr>
 <strong></strong>  
 </br>PABX: 92(42)35869507 Fax: 92(42)35830425 Email: pacra@pacra.com 
 </br>www.pacra.com
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an extra lines within your `textarea` by yourself while writing contents between `textarea` you need to place those content as

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1">NL FY 15-147 (PSO-040515)</textarea>


<textarea name="editor2" id="editor2"><b>Mr. Shahid Islam </b></br> Managing Director</br>Pakistan State Oil Company Limited</br>Karachi</textarea>
```

Comment: I will try it. Just wait for a second please

Comment: My problem about line spacing between lines is solved. But now it increase line spacing between div tag....!!!

Comment: Does it make any differences

Comment: Line spacing between lines in text area is removed. But now lines spacing increase between DIV tags

Comment: Can you please tell me how it is use?